# MySQL escaped strings problem

Tags: php, mysql

In some PHP code, I have an mysql_real_escape_string()'d term, like `foo\'s`. I search that in my database (where it is also stored as `foo\'s`) like so:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE retailerName LIKE '%" . $searchTerm . "%'");
```

The query should look like this without variables:

```
SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE retailerName LIKE '%foo\'s%'
```

If I search `f`, `fo`, or `foo`, then the search works. But if I search `foo's` then the search doesn't work (keep in mind that the actual query takes an escaped string, so everything should match up).

Comment: Perhaps your data is using curly apostrophes, and that's why it's not matching?

Comment: More code and more info, please. What does the line with mysql_real_escape_string() look like? Could you show us the error message from mysql_error()?

Comment: Are you getting a error, or no data? What is the value of the `retailerName` row you are trying to find. `foos` or `foo's`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the interface from you program to mysql (JDBC or similar) is adding extra escape characters to your string. If the same mechanism is not what put the data into the database, try doing an insert to see how the data gets stored.

Mysql can handle the query through it's own interface

```
mysql> describe test_table;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| col1  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| col2  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test_table (col1, col2) values ('col1value', 'foo\'s');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from test_table where col2 like '%foo\'s%';
+-----------+-------+
| col1      | col2  |
+-----------+-------+
| col1value | foo's |
+-----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's stored as `foo\'s` in DB, then there are 2 options - either you are double-escaping (i.e., using `mysql_real_escape_string()` twice), or you are escaping values that "something" (e.g., magic quotes) has already slashed.

Check if you have magic_quotes_gpc enabled.

Here's PHP5.3 code for stripping "magic quotes" automatically (can be used in config file). For older PHP, callback function would look differently, but you should get the idea from this.

```
// remove slashes, if they are being automatically added
if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc () ) {
    $stripslashes = function($value) use(&$stripslashes) {
        if ( is_array($value) ) {
            return array_map($stripslashes, $value);
        }
        return stripslashes($value);
    };
    $_GET    = array_map($stripslashes, $_GET);
    $_POST   = array_map($stripslashes, $_POST);
    $_COOKIE = array_map($stripslashes, $_COOKIE);
    unset($stripslashes);
}
```